# Is it possible to redirect https to http in modern browsers?

Tags: tls, http, proxy

What if I was an evil proxy operator who wanted to modify response content, but did not care if the victim sees http://? What happens if the browser requests https://example.com, but example.com **has never had** a valid SSL certificate? Will the browser automatically redirect to the http:// version? If so then an evil proxy operator should be able to simulate that response, right?

Answer (score 5):

> What happens if the browser requests https://example.com, but example.com has never had a valid SSL certificate? Will the browser automatically redirect to the http:// version?

No. Modern browsers don't downgrade to plain HTTP autonomously. If a certificate is invalid, the user will simply see a certificate warning (and eventually an option to add an exception).

> If so then an evil proxy operator should be able to simulate that response, right?

If browsers *did* redirect to plain HTTP when seeing an invalid certificate, a MITM could silently downgrade any new secure connection by modifying the transmitted certificate details. That would be a major security problem. That's why, as long as you use HTTPS right from the beginning, a MITM can't redirect you anywhere.

Rather, what an attacker can do is try to intercept a plain HTTP response before the connection is *upgraded* to HTTPS. E.g., if you type in `mybank.com`, your browser doesn't know if the site provides HTTPS yet and tries `http://mybank.com` first. Even if this HTTP site immediately responds with a redirect to `https://mybank.com`, a MITM could already intercept the response and remove the redirect to keep you on plain HTTP. (The [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) feature prevents this exact attack by instructing your browser to always visit the site over HTTPS and reject all attempts to use plain HTTP.)